# how to allow only one user to sign in with firebase authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How to allow only one user to sign in with Firebase authentication? Like in the case of an admin app, where the admin can only sign in by his email and password. I have checked that there is a way to allow only one user to sign in by the Firebase database. But I want to do that with Firebase authentication. Can anyone tell what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method to achieve that would be to [deploy and register a blocking function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#deploy_and_register_a_blocking_function). In your case, that would be in code as simple as:

```
exports.beforeSignIn = functions.auth.user().beforeSignIn((user, context) => {
  //Check to see if it is the admin
});
```

On the other hand, if you're also using Firestore, for example, you can use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). So the following rules will do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email == "admin@email.com";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Subhrajyoti. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: exports.beforeSignIn = functions.auth.user().beforeSignIn((user, context) => {
  //Check to see if it is the admin
});  What to write in this? I mean how can the app check if it is the admin?

Comment: After adding the security rules to the firebase database, what code I have to write in my app?

Comment: You have to check in the place where you store that data. If it's a database, then you have to check there. The FirebaseUser object doesn't contain that information.

Comment: So you should try to implement that, please post a new question you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect, so I or other Firebase developers can help you.