# Creating Admin Login System using Firebase Security Rules and Authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

This is a continuation question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020637/how-to-allow-only-one-user-to-sign-in-with-firebase-authentication). First Check this.

As per the answers, I have updated my security rules in my Firestore database something like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email == "...";
    }
  }
}
```

What code now I have to write in my app?

*NOTE* **I have checked all the previous questions related to this problem but that answers are not giving any solution to me**

*Remember* **The code of my app is written in react native language**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app, you need to just take the value from an email and password input, check if it is for example "admin@gmail.com" and "admin1234" if true "signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailValue, pswdValue)" which would be a bit like that (i don't code in react-native so it might not be correct but this is what you need to implement):

```
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from '@firebase/auth';

if (emailValue === 'admin@gmail.com' && pswdValue === 'admin1234') {
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, emailValue, pswdValue)
        .then(() => console.log('Sign-in successful'))
        .catch((error) => console.log('Sign-in error:', error));
}
```